# C++: Manipulating Data read in from a Text File

Tags: c++, file, file-io, indexing

I am attempting to add a a const function called ProgramAvg() to a class i'm writing that returns the average of 10 program scores. The file that I'm reading in looks like this...

```
10601   ANDRES HYUN 88 91 94 94 89 84 94 84 89 87 89 91 
10611   THU ZECHER 83 79 89 87 88 88 86 81 84 80 89 81 
10622   BEVERLEE WAMPOLE 95 92 91 96 99 97 99 89 94 96 90 97 
10630   TRUMAN SOVIE 68 73 77 76 72 71 72 77 67 68 72 75
```

The 10 program scores are the first 10 integers following the name. I'm having trouble figuring out how to read in the data and have the compiler know only to add up the first ten integers and divide it by 10. Is there a way that I could do the index of each of the program scores such as idx[3]+idx[4]+idx[5]..etc and then divide that by 10? I'm really new to C++ so if you could dumb down any and all answers that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you done your homework from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776357/c-reading-data-and-outputting-data), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777452/c-getters-and-setters) first? Post the code you have so far and what you've tried to do for obtaining at least the scores from each line, as well as your initial attempt at the average calculation.

Comment: In this case, you can use space as a tokenizer, and split your lines into segments. Then convert the segments into whatever the type it should be. You can try `STL` for this. I think it is not difficult to implement.

Comment: Post some code, it will make what you are asking for much clearer, it will also help people judge exactly how much you know and answer in a way that's more helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line you can use `std::cin` to put data into a `std::string` or `int` variable. A file stream (`std::fstream`) works the same way.

Here is an example:

```
std::string firstname, lastname;
int line; 
std::cin >> line;
std::cin >> firstname;
std::cin >> lastname;
```